# Running `cucumber feature/test.feature` in ruby shows weird behaviour

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, automation, cucumber

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
`cucumber feature/test.feature`
```

running the above code issue lots of `cucumber feature/test.feature` commands.. why ?
When i see processes list there are 30 to 50 processes running cucumber command

also ruby program never terminates

Comment: How exactly do you run `myapp.rb`?

Comment: sorry  `#!myapp.rb` is actually `#!/usr/bin/ruby`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running your feature files from outside the 'features' folder. Think this will solve the issue.(tested using the command line)

User:project user$ ls

features

User:project user$cucumber example.feature

Answer (score 0):

The first line instructs the shell to run `myapp.rb`, which is, AFAIU, this script itself. Namely, each execution of the script recursively runs itself again.

Try the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
`cucumber feature/test.feature`
```

Or, even better, directly from the CLI:

```
cucumber feature/test.feature
```

To run all the tests simply issue the `cucumber` command without args:

```
cucumber
```

Comment: Then show us the content of `feature/test.feature`. Anyway, you’ve elaborated the strange way of running `cucumber`. Why not simply run it from the command line?

Comment: I have 100+ feature files. What i am planing is to have a script that run all feature files and i will extract the results and print it in a single file(or just print the result for features that got failed)

Comment: running cucumber feature/test.feature in command line runs fine without a error(on cucumber part)

Comment: `cucumber` w/out args in the topmost directory will run all the 100+ feature files.